# django kept previous data in database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using `postgresql_psycopg2` database in one of my django powered website.Previously i have used `sqlite3` in test basis,but i have left it because now i am going to live my project in server,so we know that in `sqlite3` if we edit model,then we have to delete the whole database,cause as far as i know ,`sqlite3` don't provide any database update service or migration service.

So i have switched in to the `postgresql_psycopg2`.As i am new in django,now how can i kept my previous data after updating model.

for example i have a 
**Photo model** something like this,

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos', blank=False,null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    approved_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,null=True,blank=True)
    uploaded_time = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 500 , blank = False , null = True)
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length = 500 , blank = False , null = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

now i want to add a extra field in my `Photo` model,

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos', blank=False,null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    approved_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,null=True,blank=True)
    uploaded_time = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 500 , blank = False , null = True)
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length = 500 , blank = False , null = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #new field added
    photo_dpi = models.CharField(max_length = 500 , blank = False , null = True)
```

now how can i kept my previous data after adding a new field.

Answer (score 1):

You should use migrations to edit database structure:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/

Or, if your django version is less than 1.7, South package:

http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

Just run [`makemigrations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations) and [`migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate) commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

**UPDATE**: `makemigrations`/`migrate` commands are available since django 1.7.

As @eugene-soldatov mentioned in his answer for django 1.5 you can use the `South` app.

Another option is to alter the table manually by executing the following SQL query:

```
echo "ALTER TABLE myapp_photo ADD COLUMN photo_dpi VARCHAR(500) NULL;" | python manage.py dbshell
```

Where `myapp` is the name of your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,i am sorry forget to mention my django version,i am using django1.5.is these command will work on this version?